# How to train 10 digits number sequence as input data?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning

My input data is a set of numbers and an output number is predicted for each input number. input numbers are independent of the other and the output number is predicted based on how the input number digits are positioned.
This is a one-by-one mapping.
How do I do this?
Do I need neural networks or is there a simpler way?

Comment: you input dimension is 10 and output dimension is 10 ? always ?

Comment: input data is a 10 digits decimal integer number and output is a integer number.

Comment: if the input and output is correlated linearly, then you can simply use linear regression. If they are related in the non linear space, you can simply use an MLP(multi layer perceptron) with one node as output node and carry on with a regression.